# How to Generate a Sequence of AlphaNumberic using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i'm a newbie in javascript. As i need to generate a sequence of alphanumeric as `AB22231000`. The sequence should change every month as `AB22241000`. So the number 3 should change to 4 & 4 to 5, so on. The number should increment by 1 after every month. So anyone could please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: But it is not incrementing by 1. It is incrementing by 10,000!

Comment: No, the sequence should add only `1000` after 3 or 4 or 5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand you but I think that should help.

```js
// sequence goes here 'AB' a character, after that 2022 the year, then month , then 000
// example: 'AB' + 2022 + 1 + 000 = 'AB202201000'
const createSequence = () => {
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var sequence = 'AB' + year + month + '000';
};
```

Comment: Okay i'll try this. But it should generate a sequence of `AB222` and should add (let's consider) 10000 and should increment after every month by 10000.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: They are multiple ways to have IDs based on the date that is readable, this is a pretty strange one.

Comment: I know there's a multiple way. But it's an requirement.

Comment: So if we are in 2023 we should have 223?

Comment: And then the number are just incrementing by 10000 every month?

Comment: can you add the "real" full question?

Comment: That's the question as mentioned above

Comment: This is not a full question can you tell me what's happening between the 12.22-01.23? the example fo the responses expected

Comment: No, the number should increment by 1 i.e 10001, 10002 & so on. But after next month it should change to 20000 and increment by 1 i.e 20001,20002 & so on.

Comment: add the response to this question and I will quickly answer
12.22:?
01.23:?

Comment: Okay. So the sequence goes here 'AB' a character, after that `2022` the year, `1` or `2` the number of every month & should add `000` at the end

Comment: the format is `yyyy-mm`

Comment: Eddited tell me if this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Well, the above answer is correct but after reading your conversion, maybe I am wrong but I guess this is what you want -

```js
const createSequence = () => {
  const date = new Date();
  let day = date.getDay();
  let month = date.getMonth();
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  let sequence = 'AB' + year.toString().replace('0','') + month + '000'+day;
// this will give AB22270005
  console.log(sequence);
};
createSequence();
```

The above code will give AB22270005 here and 7 is the month so it will increase by 1 every month and 5 is the date of the day so it will also increase by one.